How to set the maxAge in NextAuth session (or session.expires) dynamically, based on a value that BE gives me?
I want to set maxAge to the value that BE gives me. BE gives me back: "expires": "2024-07-23T22:12:36.505Z" and I want that NextAuth session to be equal to this value for example. How to achieve that?
I don't want to set maxAge to a static value, because maxAge of the session can change from time to time and BE gives that in the format: "expires": "2024-07-23T22:12:36.505Z"
 import NextAuth, { Session } from 'next-auth';
    import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
    import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';
    import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
    
    let backendsSessionMaxAge: number;
    let backendSessionName: string;
    
    const authOptions = {
      providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
          name: 'Credentials',
          credentials: {
            email: { type: 'email' },
          },
          async authorize(credentials, req) {
            try {
              const response = await fetch(
                `${ENV_VARIABLE}/login`,
                {
                  method: 'POST',
                }
              );
              if (response.ok) {
                const user = await response.json();
                const setCookieHeader = response.headers.get('set-cookie');
                if (setCookieHeader) {
                  backendSessionName = setCookieHeader.split('=')[0];
                  const backendSessionValue = setCookieHeader
                    .split(';')[0]
                    .split('=')[1];
                  const maxAgeRegex = /Max-Age=(\d+)/;
                  const match = setCookieHeader.match(maxAgeRegex);
                  backendSessionMaxAge= match ? Number(match[1]) : 0;
                  cookies().set({
                    name: backendSessionName,
                    value: backendSessionValue,
                    httpOnly: true,
                    sameSite: 'lax',
                    path: '/',
                    maxAge: backendSessionMaxAge,
                  });
                }
                return user;
              } else {
                console.error(response.status);
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.error(error);
            }
          },
        }),
      ],
      callbacks: {
        async jwt({
          token,
          user,
          trigger,
          session,
        }: {
          token: JWT;
          user: Session['user'];
          trigger?: JWT['trigger'];
          session?: Session;
        }) {
          if (user) {
            token.user = user;
          }
          if (trigger === 'update' && session) {
            token = { ...token, user: session };
          }
          return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }: { session: Session; token: JWT }) {
          if (token.user) {
            session.user = token.user;
          }
          // Dynamically set the session expires
          if (backendSessionMaxAge) {
            const expirationDate = new Date(
              Date.now() + backendSessionMaxAge * 1000
            ).toISOString();
            session.expires = expirationDate;
          }
          return session;
        },
        async redirect({ url, baseUrl }: { url: string; baseUrl: string }) {
          if (url.startsWith('/')) return `${baseUrl}${url}`;
          else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url;
          return baseUrl;
        },
      },
      events: {
        async signOut() {
          cookies().set('backend-session ', '', { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'lax' });
          // empty custom cookie value
        },
      },
    session: {
    maxAge: 50, //50 seconds
    // || backendSessionMaxAge didnt get it work
  },
      pages: 
    { signIn: '/login' },
    };
    
    const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
    
    export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

